# OpenCV - blending/smoothing a seam around an object

Tags: c++, opencv, blending, boundary

I'm trying to stitch/blend a smaller, generated image with another. Basically, it's an image completion app where you select a zone and then it gets replaced with generated content from the rest of the image. I'm using Graph Cut to minimize the energy so the content itself is fine, but I can't get rid of the border:

[image]

My 2 images look like this: http://prntscr.com/kph9at

Is there a Poisson blending / seamless blending method from OpenCV (or external) that works with a hollow boundary mask?

So far I've tried the OpenCV Blender and seamlessClone (tried this: https://www.learnopencv.com/seamless-cloning-using-opencv-python-cpp/), along with a public Poisson blending cloning library I've found on github. I'm sure there's something simpler that I can do but I might lack the proper keywords to find it.

Comment: I realize this is not what you're asking about, but to be honest, in this particular example I wouldn't call the content fine, since the rather regular pattern of bricks laid in 2 orientations is suddenly broken, with a giant brick and no mortar in the middle, little misaligned fragments above it, and some really odd looking half-cut bricks below. Compared to that, the barely visible seam is quite hard to notice.

Comment: Considering your problem, could you generate the content slightly larger than the hole, and blend the transition zone (simple alpha blend).

Comment: take a look at [this](http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2017/198/)

Comment: @sturkmen thanks, but I'm doing an exemplary method (overlap lots of image candidates that match the pattern of what's missing) and I'm too far gone down that path to turn to inpainting.

Comment: @DanMašek thanks, I'll try that out now (was also thinking of finding a convolution kernel that blurs or something along that line of thought)